# What's the fastest way to ReadProcessMemory?

Tags: .net, winapi, c#-2.0, readprocessmemory

I'm trying to search for all instances of a null-terminated string the memory of a process. I enumed all the alloced memory areas with VirtualQueryEx, then I read them with ReadProcessMemory to a byte array and search using this algo (which I found here and the author claims to be the fastest)

```
    public static unsafe List<long> IndexesOf(byte[] Haystack, byte[] Needle) {
        List<long> Indexes = new List<long>();
        fixed (byte* H = Haystack) fixed (byte* N = Needle) {
            long i = 0;
            for (byte* hNext = H, hEnd = H + Haystack.LongLength; hNext < hEnd; i++, hNext++) {
                bool Found = true;
                for (byte* hInc = hNext, nInc = N, nEnd = N + Needle.LongLength; Found && nInc < nEnd; Found = *nInc == *hInc, nInc++, hInc++) ;
                if (Found) Indexes.Add(i);
            }
            return Indexes;
        }
    }
```

It works, but it's too slow. Is there a way to memory map the process or somehow search faster in its memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an external process, you pretty much have the correct approach. However, if you're looking for a string you probably don't care about certain regions (eg. executable memory) so you can exclude them from your search region. Most likely you are really only interested in `PAGE_READONLY` and `PAGE_READWRITE`.

You should read the memory in as big blocks as possible with ReadProcessMemory(). The main bottleneck will be disk IO (from swapping) and there's not much you can do about that really. Multi-threading it will speed it up because then you'll be 'buffering a read' whilst processing the previous read.

If you really need speed, the correct way to do it is not via an external process as you are doing right now. You should inject a DLL so you have direct access to the process' virtual memory space.

In your search algorithm, you can also do little tricks. For example if you know the string is always allocated on a 4 byte alignment then you can just search those. The biggest speedup you'll get is from multi-threading and/or DLL injection.

Comment: How can I exclude those regions? Those are dynamic strings by the way. They are allocated after the executable execution. Also I'm reading in big blocks (as the size of the current memory area that I'm searching in).

Comment: In VirtualQueryEx, check the MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION structure and look in the Protect member.

Comment: This made a small speedup. The string is not aligned and I don't want to inject a dll, cause the most antiviruses detect it. Is multi-threading my only hope?

Comment: I would say so. Profile your code and find where it's spending the most time. I'm relatively sure from experience it will be in the RPM.

Comment: In my not-very-scientific testing, I found that a buffer size of 2**17 (128K) is fastest on my CPU, presumably due to cache/prefetcher effects. You definitely want to check `mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT`, and you can do further filtering based on `mbi.Type` and `mbi.AllocationProtect` - not necessarily suitable for a general-purpose memory searcher, but it works if you know the string should be in the heap/image. Note that a handful of pages in the image will be `MEM_WRITECOPY` (I think these are writeable pages in the image that have not been written to yet).

Comment: Is `PAGE_READONLY` and `PAGE_READWRITE` the only two constants I would need?