# ReadProcessMemory to find a pattern - granularity?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, pattern-matching, readprocessmemory

I need to find a pattern into another process' memory and I'm using ReadProcessMemory. Since I'm using algorithms like rabin karp or similars (pattern matching) and since ReadProcessMemory copies memory (ram -> ram) to a buffer there's some slight overhead involved.. I was wondering what would be the optimal amount of memory to read each time to perform my duty

I mean: ReadProcessMemory(each_byte) sounds a lot time-expensive and ReadProcessMemory(all_the_process_memory) sounds a lot space-expensive. Is there an optimal tradeoff or a better way to set the granularity of the readings?

Comment: I would suggest profiling to find the optimal amount, I doubt there's a constant magic number.

Comment: Not sure if it's viable/relevant, but perhaps you could inject a DLL into the target process, and avoid the copy altogether? If not, running some experiments is probably the best way to find the optimal `ReadProcessMemory()` block size...

Comment: May try to read the memory with the granularity of page size - 4K. Read the question about [fastest way to ReadProcessMemory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106723/whats-the-fastest-way-to-readprocessmemory?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

When doing pattern scanning on external memory, you should read one region at a time.  The region and size should be retrieved by using VirtualQueryEx().  You should also filter out regions which are not MEM_COMMIT or are PAGE_NOACCESS regions.

Here's an example of the logic:

```
char* buffer{ nullptr };
char* addr{ nullptr };
char* match{ nullptr };
SIZE_T bytesRead;

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi{ 0 };

while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
{
    if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS)
    {
        delete[] buffer;
        buffer = new char[mbi.RegionSize];

        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, mbi.BaseAddress, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, &bytesRead);

        char* internalAddr = Compare(pattern, mask, buffer, bytesRead);

        if (internalAddr != nullptr)
        {
            //calculate from internal relative buffer to external absolute
            match = mbi.BaseAddress + (internalAddr - buffer);
            break;
        }
    }
    addr += mbi.RegionSize;
}

return match;
```

This process usually takes less than 2 seconds and shouldn't take more than 10 seconds even on a very large process.